# Splitting Button in Half

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I'm trying to split a button in half so that I can show text data in each half - which can also be increased in size when the application is expanded.

This is the code I've got soo far.

```
<Button Margin="16,0,16,6" Background="#daf0fc" BorderThickness="0" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="White" Click="edit_house" Padding="0" Focusable="False">           

<Grid>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Black">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="{Binding house_number}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" />
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding street}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding postcode}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,6,0,0" Text="{Binding house_type_text}" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="£" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FF9D1818" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="16" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding house_price}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FF9D1818" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="16" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding sold_text}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FF107910" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="14" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
```

I've tried setting each `StackPanel` half to stretch, but they both just Float in the centre of the button, so I can't align the text on either half.

Here's a graphical representation of the button I'm trying to create...

[image: Button split in half]

Update:

Here is what I'm getting with the code above, sadly I'm struggling to get the text to align, or to get anything to stretch to the full width of each half:

[image: Update image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StackPanel won't do that; it just stacks elements.

Instead, use a `<Grid>` with two columns.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've posted a view of the code I've got soo far.  It doesn't show any data when I use a grid for some reason.

Comment: That's because you're using `<ColumnDefinition Width=".50" />`. Change `.50` to `*`, or remove the Width property completely. Also, if you only have one row, you don't need to define `Grid.RowDefintions`.

Comment: You specified pixel widths (0.5 pixels).  Either don't specify any widths or specify proportion widths (`Width="1*"`)

Comment: Ok I've removed the width definitions. If you can have a look at the update image that I've added and nudge me in the right direction for getting the text to align to the left and right hand side of each half, that would be fab! I've set one of the Stackpanels to a black background so that you can see it's boundaries. Essentially I could do with the stack panels to take the full "Stretch" width of each half, but HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" doesn't seem to work. thanks again

Comment: Is it possible to get a StackPanel to align left or right inside each grid column?

Answer (score 2):

StackPanel is not the right container for this. Try using a Grid like this:

```
<Button>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
            ...
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Colunn="1">
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you could check the revision to align my text within the Stack Panels.  Thank you :)

Comment: I'm unclear about what you're trying to accomplish. Could you update the graphical representation of what you're looking for with actual aligned text?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use UniformGrids, although a Grid will also work if you need to define your Rows/Columns individually

Here's an example, with correct alignments:

```
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">

        <StackPanel Background="LightBlue" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="123" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="Main Street" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="12345" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,6,0,0" Text="Type" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Background="Yellow">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <TextBlock Text="£" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FF9D1818" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="16" />
                <TextBlock Text="100.00" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FF9D1818" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="16" />
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="200.00" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#FF107910" FontWeight="ExtraBold" FontSize="14" />
        </StackPanel>

    </UniformGrid>
```

You might also be interested in checking out [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFLayoutQS.aspx), which gives you a quick visual look at each of WPF's different layouts and how they act.